# Numbering and referencing images in Pandoc

Tags: html, latex, preprocessor, pandoc

I would like to add captions such as "Figure 1: Blah Blah" to my images in Pandoc and be able to refer to them like see @Figure1. I am using gpp (a pre-processor) to add captions to my images and do all sorts of fancy things like change size, format etc. However, I am unable to implement a counter for images like Figure1, Figure2, etc.

I have defined the following function in my gpp script:

```
\define{\counter}{0}

\defeval{count}{\eval{\counter+ 1}
```

and I call it like this in my script: `\count`

However, `\counter` doesnt get evaluated in my gpp script and I see the following `error: unfinished macro`

How should I implement this counter? I am using -T (tex) mode in gpp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found a somewhat partial solution to my problem. I found that using CSS's counter-increment property can help to auto-number images like so: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_gen_counter-reset.asp

However, the problem remains that I am using gpp to copy the same piece of code everytime my gpp tag is called. Therefore, the counter would never increment. For eg: my gpp code is:

```
\define{\image{src}{width}{caption}{tag}}{

<div style=" margin:50px auto; text-align:center;" class="figures">
<a  href="\src" id="\tag" style="margin:0px 20px; display:inline-block; 
text-decoration:none; color:black; "><img src="\src" width="\width px" 
alt="\caption" style="padding-bottom:0.5em;"> <div> \caption </div></a></div>}

\define{\imageref{label}}{
<span style="white-space:nowrap;"><a href="#\label" style="display:inline-block">\label</a></span>
}
```

My style.css looks like this:

```
div .figures{
counter-reset:figure;
}

a.figure-caption:before{
counter-increment:figure;
content: "Figure" counter(figure) ":";
}
```

Therefore, everytime I include a picture with the tag `\image`, it always gets the counter `Figure1`

Comment: Your CSS counting problem was solved in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62150847/2192488).

Answer (score 1):

You could try the [pandoc-fignos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-fignos) filter instead: it automatically creates figure numbers, and enables figure references.

In brief, you can add a label to an image like this:

```
![Caption.](image.png) {#fig:description}
```

... and then reference it like this:

```
@fig:description
```

See the [pandoc-fignos](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-fignos) page on github for installation and usage instructions.  There is also the pandoc-eqnos filter for doing the same kind of thing with equations.

Answer (score 0):

## Multilingual CSS numbering without cross-referencing

Here is a simple method for automatic CSS numbering **with labels dependent on the document language.** This simple CSS method does *not* allow for referencing.

For automatic numbering with referencing, rather use [`pandoc-fignos`](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-fignos) of the [`pandoc-xnos`](https://github.com/tomduck/pandoc-xnos) suite.

```
body {
    counter-reset: figure;
}

p.caption:before {
    counter-increment: figure;
}

p.caption:lang(en):before {
    content: 'Figure ' counter(figure) ': ';
}

p.caption:lang(nl):before {
    content: 'Figuur ' counter(figure) ': ';
}
```